# aws c++ sdk for older versions of C++

Tags: c++, aws-sdk

I have a c++ application which has lots of other third party frameworks which is not based on C++ 11 and uses VS 2008. I need to integrate some aws functionality and need to use aws C++ sdk but that seems to be on version 11 of C++ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/welcome.html

Any suggestions as to how this could be made possible?

Comment: I assume you should be able to create `C++03` compatible wrappers (or whatever standard you're using). But I would say that it's much easier to move up with the standard in the original project. There shouldn't be many things that break (for example narrowing conversions when using initializer lists)

Comment: If you are stuck with using VS 2008, this could be extremely hard or impossible depending on the AWS SDK. If they require C++11 in their external interfaces, you won't even be able to write a `C++03`/`C++98` wrapper around the `C++11` code because VS 2008 won't agree with their ABI. I would strongly suggest trying to get your code to compile under C++11 with a newer compiler. That is generally not too bad.

Comment: There is a good reason why no kernel of any commercial value has ever been written in C++. Shelf life is like 5 years max.

Comment: @Nole - And the problem here is that the *compiler* is 15 years old, and the code is newer. Not that a new compiler cannot compile the old code.

Comment: I bet a 2001 compiler would be able to compile today's Linux kernel trunk

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through this in the past with libraries provided by a Russian exchange that were like 20 years old.

The typical solution involves creating an adaptation layer which relies on C bindings, which are pretty much universal.

So basically you create a new API in C that takes string inputs and return string inputs - I would suggest Json. Then compile this library with a newer compiler.

Then go back to VS2008 and import that C library.